# Is it possible to create only ONE rule but work for all languages in SonarQube

Tags: java, sonarqube, static-code-analysis

In my situation, i need to check HTML file and Java file in the same time to find one vulnerability.But seems like i cannot check multi-language in one rule?
Is there any way to make through this?

Comment: Java is *very* different from HTML, so I can't think about anything which would apply to both, what would you have to check?

Comment: Well, it's not aimed to found a vulnerability, it's aiming to find all applications that does not use certain SDK but it should be used.So, I need to check HTML for whether the application need the SDK, and Java for whether the application using it.